Ghost comes up through the bedroom floor. The house was built over a well to hide a murder. What is the title?
I'm looking for a movie whith a child having night terrors.  The adult walks in the bedroom of the child and sees a ghost coming up from the floor.  They finally believe the child and dig up the floor to find a well.  Going into the well they find a doll stuck into the well wall.  They then find the bones of a child who was murdered.  I'm assuming the bones are of a girl.
It is not the movie "Child of Glass".  The house was a regular house not a mansion. This movie is an older movie probably made in the 1970 to 80's.

It sounds like The Changeling (1980), but the bones are of a boy.
IMDB
Trailer



Now, the ghost of the real Joseph haunts the house, making great efforts to persuade John to investigate his murder, and give him some form of justice. John's investigation leads him to a property that was once owned by the Carmichael family, and after convincing Mrs. Gray (the owner of the property and whose daughter has seen Joseph's ghost), John discovers the skeletal remains of Joseph in a well underneath the house, as well as his birth medal. Wikipedia


Wow, I think of the Changeling taking place in a mansion and I don't remember any of those scenes. (Like, I don't remember the ghost being visible.) Guess it's time for a re-watch!

This sounds a lot like The Ring (1998) or its 2002 remake. Could you have possibly got the dates wrong?
Both movies feature a mother trying to save her son from a ghosts curse by uncovering a well beneath a cabin in the woods and finding the ghost girl's corpse.
